# Excel changing Cell link from another sheet

Tags: excel, excel-2010, vba

I have main information of which i have store in sheet 1. In sheet 2 and 3 I have reference using a cell link `=Sheet1!A1`.

The problem is when I try to change values in sheet 2, it doesn't changes sheet 1 due to the fact that is showing the formula instead.

Is it possible for me to link cells from the master sheet and being able to change it from child sheet?

Thanks

Comment: Try pressing Ctrl+` on Sheets 2 and 3. Does that solve the problem?

Comment: What do you mean? Specifically with instructions if you can pal. Thanks

Comment: Switch to one of those sheets and press those keys at the same time.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you right, you want to have a kind of two way link between cells. That is not possible in Excel. You have one 'master' cell containing a value and can reference it in 'child' cells by formulas. If you change the content of the child cell, the reference is broken.

Comment: Ahhh no way... Cheers

Comment: Is there another way to do it?

Comment: Theoretically there is a possibility to achieve a similar behaviour by using the Worksheet_Change event in VBA but I would not recommend it. Such solutions tend to be buggy.